# What encryption algorithms over HTTPS (TLS) are supported by Ubuntu 16.10 trial version?

Tags: firefox, encryption, https, tls

I am using Ubuntu 16.10 trial version with Firefox, running on a hardware-write-protected USB memory, to do online banking on https sites. My PC has Windows 10 installed on the hard drive but I think this OS is not being used. This setup seems to work fine, but I cannot discover what encryption algorithm(s) are available to the TLS protocol. Apparently 9 options are possible under TLS:

1. No encryption
2. RC4 with 40-bit keys
3. RC4 with 128-bit keys
4. RC2 with 40 bit key
5. DES with 40 bit key
6. DES with 56 bit key
7. Triple-DES with 168 bit key
8. Idea (128 bit key)
9. Fortezza (96 bit key)

Can anyone tell me which are supported by Ubuntu 16.10 trial version?